# Ring polynomial kernel generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

This is the textbook question:

Q: Find generators for the kernels of the following maps:

- $\mathbb{R}[x,y] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x,y) \mapsto f(0,0)$
- $\mathbb{R}[x] \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by $f(x) \mapsto f(2+ i)$
- $\mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) \mapsto f(1+\sqrt{2})$

My work:

- Any polynomial that satisfies $f(0,0)=0$ will be in the kernel. That includes $f(x,y)=x, f(x,y)=y,f(x,y)=x+y,f(x,y)=x^7y^3 + xy^5$. I'm not sure what polynomial generates this.
- The generator of the kernel is $f(x) = x-2-i$. This seems too simple. Is this right?
- The generator of the kernel is $f(x) = x-1-\sqrt{2}$. This seems too simple. Is this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The number of generators can be more than one. Try to convince yourself that in this case the generators are $x$ and $y$.
2. Not Correct: $x-2-i$ is not an element of $\mathbb{R}[x]$!
3. Not correct! Observe that the generator must be an element of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $x - 1 -\sqrt{2}$ certainly is not.